# "Object doesn't support property or method" when I try to call plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, xpath

I'm working on a function to do some XML processing.  I'm trying to add a plugin that will let me perform XPath queries from jQuery objects.

```
function GetVersionCollection_FromLiveHistory(itemid)
{
    (function($) {
        $.xpath = function(exp, ctxt) {
            var item, coll = [],
                result = document.evaluate(exp, ctxt || document, null, 5, null);

            while (item = result.iterateNext())
                coll.push(item);

            return $(coll);
        }
    })(jQuery);

    url = "https://someSite.com/sites/xyz/_vti_bin/owssvr.dll?Cmd=Display&XMLDATA=TRUE&List={LISTGUID}&View={VIEWGUID}&IncludeVersions=TRUE&FilterField1=ID&FilterValue1=" + itemid
    returnedXml = null;
    var output=$.get(url,function(returnedXml){
        elVersions=$.parseXML(returnedXml);
        var result={};
        $(elVersions).xpath("//z:row").each(function(index,element){
            versionNumber=$(this).attr('ows__UIVersionString');
            result[versionNumber]=$(this);
            return result;
        });
    },"xml");
    return output;
}
```

When I call it, the browser returns an error that seems to indicate that `xpath` has not been successfully added as a jQuery plugin, when it reaches the `$(elVersions).xpath("//z:row")...` line.

IE:

```
Object doesn't support property or method 'xpath'
```

Chrome:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).xpath is not a function
```

Comment: What happens if you try to assign the function to `$.fn.xpath` instead of `$.xpath`?

Comment: @dreyescat, that did something, now i'm getting a different error instead: `Uncaught NamespaceError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//z:row' contains unresolvable namespaces.`

Comment: @sigil Not sure I can help you out with this... I'm not very good at XML and Namespaces, and less using XPath ;). But maybe in your `document.evaluate` you need to specify somehow the namespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you are getting this error because you are not creating a jQuery plugin but adding a function to the jQuery object.

You need to assign the function to `$.fn` and it will be available just like any other jQuery object method.

```
$.fn.xpath = function(exp, ctxt) {
```